# Vulcanize, what's the point?

Tags: performance, polymer, vulcanize

Just in general why would one consider to vulcanize a web page. For example now I am building a website that is about 629kb, in 975ms(under 30m/s wifi network), with 93 requests.

After vulcanizing my page, it becomes 964kb, in 2.02s load time, but 47 requests only.

I do have some polymer-project components in there otherwise it is a pretty straightforward website with sass. Not built upon any framework.

So my question is what's the big fuzz with Vulcanization? Am i missing something here? It seems to have decreased the performance of the website.

Comment: 47 requests sound a little bit much, if you properly vulcanize it. All your imports should be collapsed to a single import. It should definately make a big impact. Is there an online verison of the page to test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, Vulcanizing should bring your JS requests to 1 and CSS requests to 1. Eliminating round trip latency is HUGE for actual users. Be sure to test your performance using webpagetest.org or at least locally using throttling to test different network speeds (Chrome has this built into the dev tools).

All that being said, HTTP2 changes all this and makes vulcanizing less important.